# Error "Expected only one document in this file but found multiple" in tavern

Tags: api, yaml, pytest, tavern

I use common.yaml file for sharing stages but If I add more than one stage it's showing error "tavern.util.exceptions.UnexpectedDocumentsError:". Do I have to add separate yams file for each stage?

My common.yaml file

```
name: Test /order endpoint status code and response
description:
  Reusable test stage to get listings

stages:
  - id: get_listings
    name: Test to get all the listings 
    request:
       url: 
      method: POST
      headers:
        Authorization: 
 ---
name: Test /status endpoint to create order
description:
  Reusable test stage for order creation

stages:
  - id: create_order
    name: Test to create an order
    skip: False
    request:
      url: 
      method: POST
      headers:
        Authorization:
```

Testfile.yaml

```
test_name: Test endpoint

includes:
 - !include common.yaml

stages:

  - type: ref

    id: get_listings

  - type: ref1

    id: create_order
```

Comment: When presenting code, config or logs here, please use the formatting tool provided in the editor. Markdown format is supported.

Comment: Sorry about that..I will keep this in mind..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!include` cannot handle a file with multiple documents since it basically replaces the current node with the content from the referred document, starting at its root node. Since a file with multiple documents has multiple root nodes, it's unclear what `!include` should do there.

That being said, you can of course simply define both stages in the same document:

```yaml
# [snip]

stages:
  - id: get_listings
    name: Test to get all the listings 
    request:
       url: 
      method: POST
      headers:
        Authorization:
  - id: create_order
    name: Test to create an order
    skip: False
    request:
      url: 
      method: POST
      headers:
        Authorization:
```